# Calculate log of number less than raised to power

Tags: logarithms

I want to calculate the value of 0.9 raised to power 17.I am using the log method.

17 * log(0.9).Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your answer is incomplete. Once you calculate $17 \times \log(0.9)$, you need to take the anti-log to get the actual value of $0.9^{17}$. Assuming your log was the natural log, you would calculate $e^{17 \times \log(0.9)}$ to get what you want.